# How to check Last Modified Date is between 30 and 60 days in apex?

Tags: date, apex

I have a requirement in Apex where I have to write a query for a Batch class with a condition that the Last Modified date should be between 30 and 60 days and this should be configurable by user. I have created a custom setting for this to make it configurable but couldn't find anything to check date between 30 and 60 days. Is there any formula which can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for is SOQL [Date Literals](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_dateformats.htm). Below is the sample query:

```
SELECT Id, Name, LastModifiedDate FROM Account WHERE LastModifiedDate < LAST_N_DAYS:30 AND LastModifiedDate >= LAST_N_DAYS:60 ORDER BY LastModifiedDate
```

I would create the string query as follows:

```
String strStartNumberOfDays = '30'; // replace with your custom setting value
String strEndNumberOfDays = '60'; // replace with your custom setting value

String strQuery = 'SELECT Id, Name, LastModifiedDate FROM Account WHERE LastModifiedDate < LAST_N_DAYS:' + strStartNumberOfDays + ' AND LastModifiedDate >= LAST_N_DAYS:' + strEndNumberOfDays + ' ORDER BY LastModifiedDate';
```